# Call method of presenting viewcontroller from modal

Tags: ios, swift3, viewcontroller

I have a `ViewController`: if a user is not logged in, I open modally a new controller, so that the user can login. The opening is done this way:

```
if(!loggedIn){
             self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"loginView", sender:self)
        }
```

After login, I want to dismiss this modal and come back to my viewcontroller: this is very easy to do, but I want another thing. I want the presenting view controller call this method before I dismiss my modal:

```
 func goToContent(animated:Bool){
        let viewController:ContentViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Content") as! ContentViewController
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
    }
```

Is this possible? From my modal I could not get a reference to the presenting viewController. That is: I tried the following, but I don't know if this is the right way to proceed:

```
let vc:ViewController = ViewController()
vc.goToContent(animated:false)
```

This works but aren't there better solutions?

[Edit to reply to a question in the comments]
I implemented a delegate this way:

in the ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, LoginViewControllerDelegate {

    var loginViewController:LoginViewController = LoginViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loginViewController.delegate = self
    }
```

In LoginViewController file, just before the class declaration:

```
protocol LoginViewControllerDelegate: class {

    func goToContent(animated:Bool)

}
```

Inside LoginViewController:

```
weak var delegate: LoginViewControllerDelegate?
```

in its view did load (just for testing: I simply put a print inside the body of goToContent):

```
delegate?.goToContent()
```

Comment: did you try this ...if yes what is the problem occurs ?

Comment: There's no problem: I want to know if instatiating the presenting view controller from my modal is the right way to proceed. I could not get a reference to my presentingviewcontroller because it was opened through a segue (performSegue)

Comment: please add your code for present ?

Comment: What so you really want to achieve?

Comment: @HermannKlecker: from the modal I want to call a method on the presenting view controller (no matter if this method pushes another viewcontroller)

Comment: Before calling `delegate?.goToContent()` please check whether delegate is nil or not.

Comment: print(delegate ?? "it is nil") returns "it is nil"

Comment: Wouldn't be way more easy if presentingViewController worked even when using segues?

Comment: @IanBell If delegate is nil you are assigning it in wrong way or after assigning delegate you are re-initilizing your LoginViewControllerDelegate,thats why it is nil

Comment: Maybe I oversimplified my scenario, I'll try to ask a better question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a delegate of `ContentViewController` and in that delegate you need to add this method `goToContent`.

Now when you are logged in successfully, you need to call this delegate method. It will work.

Comment: But ContentViewController is the screen I open using a segue from the "base" viewcontroller that opens the modal first and gotoContent is a function contained in that view controller

Comment: Then you need to create a delegate of `ViewController `

Comment: So, I don't need to create an instance of ViewController?

Comment: No you don't need to create the instance of ViewController(), call the delegate, it will handle it.

Comment: I suppose the ViewController (that launches the modal), apart from conforming to a protocol declared in LoginView, must instantiate a member of LoginView and set its delegate to self. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you need to set the delegate to self, then only delegate will work

Comment: just an advice, not something I need to know: is sending a notification (NSNotification) a bad idea in cases like this?

Comment: @IanBell Well NSNotifications are used from one to many communication while delegates are use for one to one, so in your case, delegates will be the best way, I also suggest you to go through some links about delegates.

Comment: problem is not (I think) links, I have used delegates in the past. Problem is the way I explained the issue: I "atomized" the situation too much and there are many other variables to take into account. I'll try to post a better post, I've been unforgivably superficial. Thanks for your time

Comment: I posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546901/call-uiviewcontroller-method-from-uiviewcontroller-deeply-nested-in-a-modal (just in case you are interested)