# Call UIViewController method from UIViewController deeply nested in a modal

Tags: ios, swift3

In my app I have a “main” `ViewController`. On app launch in the body of its `viewDidAppear`, I retrieve the value of a `UserDefaults boolean`: if the user is not logged in, I present modally another `viewcontroller` this way:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"loginView", sender:self)
```

This launches modally `AuthViewController`, a viewcontroller that contains a “Container View”, a region of AuthViewController that includes a `UIPageViewController` (`AuthPageViewController`).

This last one has two “pages”: `LoginViewController` and `RegisterViewController`.

[image: More than a thousand words]

`LoginViewController` is used to login users: once the user is logged in I want to call a function (no matter what it does) on the main `ViewController`.

So, to summarize, I’m in `LoginViewController` and I want to call a method of `ViewController`.

While trying a solution I discovered the following:

- I can’t get a reference to `presentingViewController` because `LoginViewController` has not been opened directly from ViewController. Moreover, `AuthViewController` was not launched with `present(_:animated:completion:)` but with `self.performSegue` as I said before;
- instantiating a `ViewController` from `LoginViewController` and calling a method works but it’s not a good idea;
- `NSNotification` works like a charm;
- apparently delegates aren’t working or I’m missing something about their implementation in the contest of this app;

Can you help me understand how to call a ViewController method from my LoginViewController? Code examples are very well received, but I appreciate any advice.

Comment: delegate will work if you init the `LoginViewController` from the `ViewController `, else just use notification, unwind may work also if u dismiss multiple at same time

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain it with code of how to use delegate in this case,

First you need create a delegate in `LoginViewController` like this

```
protocol LoginViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func goToContent(animated:Bool)
}
```

then create a variable for delegate like this

```
weak var delegate: LoginViewControllerDelegate?
```

Now in you `ViewController` you have to assign the `delegate` like this in your prepare `prepareforsegue` method, as you are using segue like this

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "yourSegueIdentifier" {
        let nextScene =  segue.destination as! LoginViewController
        nextScene.delegate = self
    }
}
```

and implement that method like this

```
func goToContent(animated: Bool) {
    print("test")
}
```

in this way you are able to call `goToContent` from `LoginViewController`

Comment: Ok, interesting, thanks! Meantime I found another way, way less elegant, to achieve the same result: in the prepareForSegue I set a property on the destination viewcontroller, passing it self. When I need it from LoginViewController, I reach it through a "chain" of parent. I did not like it but it worked. :-)

Comment: Yeah you can also do it like that way, but try this solution once

Comment: Wait a moment, Rajat: ViewController doesn't actually prepare a segue for LoginViewController, but for its "granpa" AuthViewController